# Debian package conflicts

Tags: dpkg, debian

I'm trying to find out what package is conflicting my gksu package, so does anybody know what command can I use?

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Comment: You need to edit this question to make it more informative. For now I would say the answer is: no. We need more info. Like what notices do you get?

Comment: Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Comment: I don't know what man command tells you what package is conflicting the other

Comment: edit the question; dont use comments.

Comment: and why is this marked debian?

Answer (score 2):

That warning goes away with `sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module` but it is just a warning, nothing that would conflict with installing software.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you do dpkg -s "package" and it tells you what package has conflicted